# Printing array adds 48 to expected value

Tags: c++, arrays, function

This is part of a larger bit of code, but the output is odd, when I do it without functions, aka putting all the arguments in the main function it works correctly. But when I do it in the functions, it adds 48 for a reason beyond me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define N 3

void print_into_file();
int current_board(int Y, int X);

int X, Y;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    print_into_file();

}

int current_board(int Y, int X)
{
    char current_array [N][N] = 
    {
        {'1', '2', '3'},
        {'4', '5', '6'},
        {'7', '8', '9'}
    };

    return current_array[Y][X];
}

void print_into_file()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("printtest.txt");

    for(Y = 0; Y < N; Y++)
    {
        for(X = 0; X < N; X++)
        {
            myfile << "| " << current_board(Y, X) << " ";
        }

        myfile << "|" << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

The output of this program is

| 49 | 50 | 51 |

| 52 | 53 | 54 |

| 55 | 56 | 57 |

But it should be

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

| 7 | 8 | 9 |

I am not sure what is wrong.

I am sort of new to c++ so it's probably something obvious that I can't spot.

Comment: You have not initialized the array which integers. You have initialized it with ASCII characters `'1'` through `'9'`. If you look up an ASCII table, you will see where these values come from.

Comment: The ASCII value of '1' is 49.  And '2' is 50.  Et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int current_board(int Y, int X)
```

returns an `int`, so `cout` prints the integer code for the corresponding character. Change the return type of this function to `char` and `cout` will interpret it as such.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you print an integer, you have to print a char.